# How to select last row with data but columns C to L

Tags: excel, vba

I have this piece of code below that finds the last row with data and changes the cell colour, however I only want it to do this for the last row of columns C - L rather than the entire row.

I appreciate this is probably just something simple that I have overlooked but Iv been looking around for the answer and tweaking my code unsuccessfully for hours and scratching my head.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Dim lngLastRow As Long

    Range("a7").End(xlDown).Select

    lngLastRow = ActiveCell.Row

    Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
    Cells(lngLastRow, "A").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Range("C:L").Find(What:="*", After:=Range("C1"), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Cells(lr, "C").Resize(1, 10).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nicely done. Not obvious to all: The '10' actually stands for Range("C:L").Columns.Count.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `Cells(lngLastRow, "C").Select` just before `Selection.Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)`

have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

to act on given columns, you can use `Intersect()` method of `Range` object:

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    Intersect(Range("C:L"), Range("a7").End(xlDown).EntireRow).Interior.Color = RGB(242, 242, 242)
End Sub
```